# Why would creating a user namespace with size 1 work but size >1 fail

Tags: linux, userns

I am experimenting with unprivileged linux containers and I am writing a Go program that creates a minimalist container. The program forks itself and creates namespaces in the process. However for some reason if I set the user namespace size to greater than 1, it fails when running as a regular user.

```
    cmd := exec.Command("/proc/self/exe", "run-container")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags:   syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER | syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWPID | syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
        Unshareflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWNS,
        UidMappings: []syscall.SysProcIDMap{
            {
                ContainerID: 0,
                HostID:      os.Getuid(),
                Size:        1,   // set this to 2 or more and it fails
            },
        },
        GidMappings: []syscall.SysProcIDMap{
            {
                ContainerID: 0,
                HostID:      os.Getgid(),
                Size:        1,
            },
        },
    }
    // other flags: CLONE_NEWNET, CLONE_NEWIPC, CLONE_NEWCGROUP, CLONE_NEWUSER,
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR: parent cmd.Run", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

The code above (along with all the other stuff like pivot_root etc.. ) works fine. But the moment I set Size to 2, it bombs:

```
ERROR: parent cmd.Run fork/exec /proc/self/exe: operation not permitted
```

This seems to be a capabilities issue because when I run as root it works.

Here is my `/etc/subuid`:

```
lxd:1000:1
root:1000:1
lxd:100000:65536
root:100000:65536
developer:165536:65536
mounter:231072:65536
```

### Update:

I figured out that you need CAP_SETUID to map more than just the current `euid` to another (see [user namespaces man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html)).

But even after `sudo setcap cap_setuid=eip /my/binary` it fails. The error message has changed to:

```
ERROR: parent cmd.Run fork/exec /proc/self/exe: permission denied
```

If I run `strace` it fails with `EPERM` when trying to write to `/proc/xx/uid_map`.

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/25233/uid_map", O_RDWR) = 5
write(5, "0 1000 100\n\0", 12)          = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Running a program using `strace` disables setuid and file capabilities. With root privileges you can attach to any running program.